# Why did Harry fall in the Interrogation Court Room in GoF but not in subsequent memory viewings via the Pensieve?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did Harry fall in the Interrogation Court Room in GoF when viewing Karkaroff's trial but not in subsequent memory viewings via the Pensieve, such as Bob Ogden, Tom Riddle at the Orphanage, Morfin Gaunt, Hokey the House-Elf/Hepzibah Smith, wherein he was instead viewing it from a different perspective?

Answer (score 1):

In all of the cases you mention, Harry did indeed fall:

### Bob Ogden

> Harry bent forward, took a deep breath, and plunged his face into the silvery substance. He felt his feet leave the office floor; **he was falling, falling through whirling darkness** and then, quite suddenly, he was blinking in dazzling sunlight. Before his eyes had adjusted, Dumbledore landed beside him.

### Tom Riddle at the Orphanage

> Harry bent over the Pensieve; his face broke the cool surface of the memory **and then he was falling through darkness again....** Seconds later, his feet hit firm ground; he opened his eyes and found that he and Dumbledore were standing in a bustling, old-fashioned London street.

### Morfin Gaunt

> Harry stepped up to the stone basin and bowed obediently until his face sank through the surface of the memory; he felt the familiar sensation of **falling through nothingness** and then landed upon a dirty stone floor in almost total darkness.

### Hokey the House-Elf/Hepzibah Smith

> Harry got to his feet and bent once more over the rippling silver contents of the stone basin until his face touched them. **He tumbled through dark nothingness** and landed in a sitting room in front of an immensely fat old lady wearing an elaborate ginger wig and a brilliant pink set of robes that flowed all around her, giving her the look of a melting iced cake.

Comment: What about Snape's memories in Deathly Hallows?

Comment: @KyleV There too: *He fell headlong into sunlight*